# AES256 decryption corrupting first bytes

Tags: c#, aes

I've been around this problem for some hours now, and I still can't find why it happens.

I have a string that it encrypted with AES, and then decrypted back to it's original state. However, the decryption seems to modify the original string, corrupting the first bytes.

Instead of returning `bc85f420763f79e6`**9becb**`...`, it returns `?OqG?b3Mf~ J???j`**9becb**`...`, then keeps returning the rest of the plain text correctly.

Here's the methods I used to encrypt and decrypt:

```
private byte[] EncryptAES256(string text, byte[] key)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    if (key == null || key.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

    byte[] encryptedText;
    try
    {
        AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        aes.Key = key;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {

                    swEncrypt.Write(text);
                }
                encryptedText = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception exceptionToBeThrown = new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        throw exceptionToBeThrown;
    }
    return encryptedText;
}

private string DecryptAES256(byte[] text, byte[] key)
{
    if (text == null || text.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    if (key == null || key.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

    string decryptedText;
    try
    {
        AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        aes.Key = key;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(text))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    decryptedText = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception exceptionToBeThrown = new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        throw exceptionToBeThrown;
    }
    return decryptedText;
}
```

Did I mess something up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using different IVs when encrypting and decrypting.
When decrypting you must specify the same IV as the one you used when encrypting the data.

From the docs of GenerateIV (emphasis mine):

> Generates a **random** initialization vector (IV) to be used for the algorithm.

You can either use a constant IV that you define in your code and pass to the AesManaged instance, or you can store the IV that was used to encrypt the data along with the data and then read it before decrypting the rest.

Comment: Would that cause a security problem? (I'm still learning how encryption and decryption works)

Comment: Honestly I don't really know. My gut tells me that using a constant IV would be bad. However I'm not that deep into encryption myself.

Comment: @PeterAS17 : Storing the IV with the data is safer than using a static/constant one (infact it makes the data harder to read for someone on the outside, as they don't know that **x** bytes of it are the IV). As long as the key is secret you should be fine.

Comment: @PeterAS17 : I found this quite interesting: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12076

Comment: Thanks for the link @Visual Vincent. I actually thought it'd be a security breach if I'd store it with the data. And thanks Sylence for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is failing is because you are not setting the IV key. Instead you Generate two different IV for the Encrypt and Decrypt method.

```
aes.GenerateIV();
```

Whenever you want to encrypt and decrypt data you have to ensure that the Salt en IV is the same. What you want to do is add the IV from your encrypted method to the beginning of your encrypted byte array. Something like:

```
byte[] IV = aesAlg.IV;
byte[] combinedIvCt = new byte[IV.Length + encrypted.Length];
Array.Copy(IV, 0, combinedIvCt, 0, IV.Length);
Array.Copy(encrypted, 0, combinedIvCt, IV.Length, encrypted.Length);

return Convert.ToBase64String(combinedIvCt.ToArray());
```

And once decrypting take the first 16 bytes of the encrypted result you are trying to decrypt. This would be your IV key:

```
byte[] IV = new byte[16];
byte[] Encoded = new byte[inputAsByteArray.Length - IV.Length];
Array.Copy(inputAsByteArray, 0, IV, 0, IV.Length);
Array.Copy(inputAsByteArray, IV.Length, Encoded, 0, Encoded.Length);

//later in your code....
//Encoding = the data you are going to decrypt.  

aesAlg.IV = IV;
```

You can do the same if you would like to add a salt. Whatever you do though never hardcode your salt or IV. This is a interesting read: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49031/is-it-safe-to-write-the-salt-and-or-the-iv-at-the-beggining-of-an-encrypted-file

Comment: Thanks for you help and link you provided. Code working, though you forgot a comma :) `Array.Copy(inputAsByteArray, 0` **,** `IV, 0, IV.Length);`